# Updating rtk query cache validity dynamic for same endpoint

Tags: rtk-query

I'm using RTK query in my application.
I've a single endpoint, there I'm passing different data in request params to load different set of data.

Now for different set of data I want to maintain different cache validity time.

I'm following this doc:
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/cache-behavior#reducing-subscription-time-with-keepunuseddatafor
Here I've example like this.

```
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPosts: builder.query<Post[], number>({
      query: () => {
        url,
        method,
        body
      },
      // configuration for an individual endpoint, overriding the api setting
      keepUnusedDataFor: 5,
    }),
  }),
```

Here I can see I have option to set `keepUnusedDataFor` in the base level and for different api endpoints we have option to change `keepUnusedDataFor` for that specific endpoint.

But as I mentioned I've single endpoint but multiple query params for different set of data. So is there a option to `keepUnusedDataFor` with the query params?

I mean something similar to:

```
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPosts: builder.query<Post[], number>({
      query: () => {
        url,
        method,
        body,
        keepUnusedDataFor
      },
    }),
  }),
```

Or any other approach to achieve this?

Comment: What query parameters are you referring to? Please [edit] the post to include a complete and relevant [mcve] of the code you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you already know the answer to your own question. As the data fetched for that endpoint is cached for 60 seconds except if altered using `keepUnusedDataFor: 10`

but when another variable changes for another data you can't change the keepUnusedDataFor value. As its fixed for each endpoint.

Please this is my own view though. Things can change in the future though.

Have a lovely day.